# dropdownlist properties of SelectedItem ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a table whith columns Id, Name, Attack, SortOfWeapon. And in dropdownlist Text="Name" and Value="Id". When I click on button, could I take other properties of SelectedItem(Country and Zip)?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Weapon weapon in GetWeapons())
        {
            DropDownListOfWeapon.Items.Add(weapon.Name);
        }

    }
protected IEnumerable<Weapon> GetWeapons()
    {
        return weaponRepository.Weapons
            .OrderBy(a => a.Name);

    }
```

When user select item and click on button, property values of selected item must be supplied in the function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150214/asp-net-how-to-create-cascading-dropdownlists-boxes-using-single-data-table/39230066#39230066? Your question looks similar

Comment: What do you mean take other values? are you looking for cascading drop downs, (so you select an item in the first, and it is used to populate a second with relevent data), or are you looking to select an item in teh dropdown list, and then access all the properties of the selected item?
And why write your question about addresses if the code sample is about weapons ? Makes it hard for anyone to give you a relevent example!

Comment: @VDWWD sorry, but I dont understand your example. How could I apply to properties of selectedItem? In webforms, if I use List<> as DataSourse, I could apply to all properties of SelectedItem.

Comment: @Matt Sorry for code-example. Yes, i want to  to select an item in teh dropdown list, and then access all the properties of the selected item.

Comment: In that case, you have 3 options (broadly speaking.)
1) Add all the objects data to the page (such as in a javascript array, or as a series of hidden panels) then when an option is selected, use some javascript to display the relevent data.
2) Use some kind of ajax solution, so when an item is selected you cal back to the server and ask it to give you the relevent object
3) Just post back to the server, and reload the page with the selected data (or even direct to a new page with the information on.)
Hard to say which is best for you. Maybe update your question with your intent?

Comment: @Matt add some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this (not 100% sure though)

In the aspx page:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListOfWeapon" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListOfWeapon_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

In code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check for postback
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //fill the dropdown
            DropDownListOfWeapon.DataSource = GetWeapons();
            DropDownListOfWeapon.DataTextField = "Name";
            DropDownListOfWeapon.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownListOfWeapon.DataBind();

            //add a select text at the first position
            DropDownListOfWeapon.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a weapon", "-1", true));
        }
    }

    private List<Weapon> GetWeapons()
    {
        //create a new list
        List<Weapon> weaponList = new List<Weapon>();

        //fill the list with dummy weapons
        //this probly would come from a database or other external source
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
            weapon.Id = i;
            weapon.Name = "Weapon " + i;
            weapon.Attack = "Attack " + i;
            weapon.SortOfWeapon = "Sort of weapon " + i;
            weaponList.Add(weapon);
        }

        //sort the list alphabetically
        weaponList = weaponList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

        return weaponList;
    }

    protected void DropDownListOfWeapon_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the id from the dropdown
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListOfWeapon.SelectedValue);

        if (Id < 0)
        {
            //clear the literal when no selection is made
            Literal1.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            //get the correct weapon from the list based on it's id using Linq
            List<Weapon> weaponList = GetWeapons().Where(x => x.Id == Id).ToList();

            //show the properties in the literal
            Weapon weapon = weaponList[0];
            Literal1.Text = weapon.Id + "<br />";
            Literal1.Text += weapon.Name + "<br />";
            Literal1.Text += weapon.Attack + "<br />";
            Literal1.Text += weapon.SortOfWeapon + "<br />";
        }
    }

    //the weapon class
    class Weapon
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Attack { get; set; }
        public string SortOfWeapon { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Seems that is what i looking for, thanks!(sorry that I couldnt vote for your answer-low repo)